# springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() returns false inside @MessageMapping function

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm attempting a simple chat that requires the user to be logged in to use. I've gotten the login working, and can detect it in the controller with springSecurityService.isLoggedIn(). However, when calling that function inside the chat handler, it will always return false. The function in question:

```
@MessageMapping("/sendchat")
@SendTo("/topic/chats")
protected String sendchat(String getrequest) {
   log.info "\n\npre login"
   if(springSecurityService.isLoggedIn())
   {
      log.info "\n\n"+getrequest
      //do other things if successful
   }
   else
   {
      log.info "\n\nnot logged in"
   }

}
```

It will always execute the else statement, even when the index() function of the controller has correctly detected the user as logged in.

Answer (score 0):

That is because "springSecurityService" is work only for Controller action methods, the "spring-security-core plugin" use filters to setup security-context, then the springSecurityService can retrieve the user login status.

While in your code, the method is "protected" and it is a "websocket plugin" convention, so you should do security according to the plugin document, like this:

```
class ExampleController {

    @ControllerMethod
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @SendTo("/topic/hello")
    String hello(String world) {
        return "hello from secured controller, ${world}!"
    }

    @ControllerMethod
    @MessageExceptionHandler
    @SendToUser(value = "/queue/errors", broadcast = false)
    String handleException(Exception e) {
        return "caught ${e.message}"
    }

}
```

More details can reference "https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket#securing-message-handler-methods".

Comment: ControllerMethod and PreAuthorize cause "unable to resolve class" errors. What do I need to import to solve this?

Comment: PreAuthorize is a class in "spring-security-core" plugin, so you need that dependencies. ControllerMethod is in grails-web-common jar, I use grails 4.0.1, it should be automatically included.